# Limit inferior and superior proof questions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I've written some answers to questions in my textbook. Can someone please verify them or offer suggestions for improvement?

(Q1) Let $(s_n)$ be a bounded sequence and $k$ be a positive real number. Then, lim sup $ks_n = k$ lim sup $s_n$

Solution: Let $\epsilon > 0$ and lim sup $s_n = s$.

Then, $\exists N_0$ such that $\forall N > N_0$, sup $\{s_n | n>N\} < s + \frac{\epsilon}{k}$.

This implies that $\forall n > N_0$, $s_n < s + \frac{\epsilon}{k}$. So, $ks_n - ks < \epsilon$.

Therefore, sup $\{ ks_n | n > N_0 \} \leqslant ks + \epsilon$.

Since this is true $\forall \epsilon > 0$, sup $\{ ks_n | n > N_0 \} \leqslant ks$.

It remains to show that $\forall \delta > 0, $ lim sup $ks_n \geqslant ks - \delta$.

Suppose $\exists \delta_0 > 0$ such that lim sup $ks_n < ks - \delta_0$.

Then, $\exists N_1$ such that $\forall n > N_1$, sup $\{ks_n | n > N_1\} < ks - \frac{\delta}{2}$

So, $\forall n > N_1$, $ks_n < ks-\frac{\delta_0}{2}$

This implies that $\forall n > N_1$, $ks_n < ks - \frac{\delta_0}{2}$.

So, $s_n < s - \frac{\delta_0}{2k} \forall n > N_1$.

This implies that lim sup $s_n < s$, a contradiction. Therefore, lim sup $ks_n$ = $k$ lim sup $s_n$

(Q2) Show that lim inf $(s_n+t_n) \geqslant$ lim inf $s_n + $ lim inf $t_n$

Solution: Let $\alpha = $ inf $\{s_n|n>N_0\}$ and $\beta = $ inf $\{t_n|n>N_0\}$.

Then, $\forall n > N_0$, $\alpha \leqslant s_n$ and $\beta \leqslant t_n$. Therefore, $\forall n > N_0$, $\alpha + \beta \leqslant s_n+t_n$

Hence, $\alpha + \beta \leqslant$ inf $\{s_n+t_n|n>N_0\}$

Using limit theorems, we arrive at the conclusion that lim inf $(s_n+t_n) \geqslant$ lim inf $s_n + $ lim inf $t_n$